# If elif else not working in bash ChromeOS

Tags: bash, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I am trying to make a bash script which basically takes a bunch of .debs, unpacks them and place binaries and libs in /usr/local/opt/{lib}bin.

The script checks whether / is mounted as ro or rw, and if mounted as ro to remount it as rw. 
On chromebooks however, in order to mount / as rw you need to remove_rootfs_verification for the partition in question. The script fails to echo what stated above when rootfs_verification is enabled for /, and should exit 1, instead it carries on.

Here is the part of the script I am referring to

```
### ChromeOS's Specific!!!
# The following assumes rootfs_verification for / has already been removed 
if grep $rootfs /proc/mounts | grep ro; then
  mount -o remount,rw / &> mount.out 

elif 
 grep -iw 'read-write' mount.out; then 

   echo '\nrootfs_verification for the root partition must to be removed in order to remount,rw  /
To remove rootfs_verification run the following command and than reboot the system:
"sudo /usr/share/vboot/bin/make_dev_ssd.sh  --remove_rootfs_verification --partitions 4"'

else exit 1

fi
```

The entire WIP script can be found here https://pastebin.com/ekEPSvYy

This is what happen when I execute it

```
localhost /usr/local # ./kvm_install.sh 
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   124    0   124    0     0    322      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   345
100   135  100   135    0     0    170      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   170
100 60384  100 60384    0     0  57950      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  344k
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   143    0   143    0     0    407      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   412
100   154  100   154    0     0    202      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   202
100 1298k  100 1298k    0     0   929k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 3020k
/dev/root / ext2 ro,seclabel,relatime,block_validity,barrier,user_xattr,acl 0 0
./kvm_install.sh: line 31: /etc/env.d/30kvm: Read-only file system
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 66802  100 66802    0     0  69657      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 74555
./kvm_install.sh: line 39: ar: command not found
tar (child): control.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
md5sum: md5sums: No such file or directory
```

Basically what happens here is ar cannot be found as the script was unable to add the PATH variables to /etc/env.d/30kvm since the root partition cannot be mounted because roots_verification is enabled on /.

I tried adding the elif "grep" command in [[ as some suggested here, but that didn't work and adds further syntax issues.

I am in the process of learnign the basics of bash scripting. I apologize if the script is written poorly.

Thanks

**I ultimately ended up doing this.**

```
 if grep $rootfs /proc/mounts | grep 'ro,'; then
      mount -o remount,rw / &> mount.out

if
    grep 'read-write' mount.out; then
     echo 'something to echo' && exit 1
    fi
    fi
```

It is not pretty, but it works until I find/ learn a better way to implement the loop.

Comment: `mount.out` is only created in the `if` section. If there is one available to read in the `elif` section it's not the one that was created directly above, it is from your previous successful `if` run. That can't be good ;-) I don't do enough with `mount` options to be able to offer useful comments on that. Seems like you understand the problem, but I would add debugging statements like `echo "inside elif"` so you are sure the script is following the path you expect. Good luck.

Comment: Also note that `grep ro` will match `/dev/root / ext2 rw` as well as `/dev/root / ext2 ro`

Comment: @shellter  I am not entirely sure what you meant with: "mount.out is only created in the if section. If there is one available to read in the elif section it's not the one that was created directly above, it is from your previous successful if run. " Thanks

Comment: I should have prefaced that comment with "Based on the code you have provided", but now I recall you have only included part of your script. In any case, your `mount.out` may be suspect as you're examining it in the `elif` portion, so be sure that it has current information in it. I think my debug idea is where you should start, if you're still having trouble. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

to make the output of a command a variable do:

```
$variable="$(command)"
```

if you want to use grep use the syntax:

```
command | grep text
```

if you want to do if statements use the syntax:

```
if [ some text ]; text
    commands
elif [ some text ]
    commands
else
    commands
fi
```

[for the some text check this cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VW29.png)

grep -iw is not valid on chromebook

rootfs has a different path depending on a lot of things if you want to save it as $rootfs do this command

```
rootfs="$(rootdev -s)"
```

also you made some mistake is the "|" and "&"

```
command1 | command to edit command1
command1 || run this command if command1 fails
command1 && run this command if command1 succeeds
```